# Is there a way to create a ranged for-loop in C++17 without memory charge?

Tags: for-loop, c++17

Is there a way to create a ranged for-loop in C++17 or maybe in Boost without charges, for instance:

```
for (int i : {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}) {
    <...>
}
```

or

```
char arr[100];
for (char i : arr) {
    <...>
}
```

Would be at least non-memory-optimized. And it's too verbose.

How it should be written?

I'm interested in other ways than just the following:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
    <...>
}
```

Comment: In boost: irange, counting_range, etc.

Comment: Just out of couriosity - what is that good for?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler on demand computation may introduce serious performance benefits. See my answer - I encourage you to read about `C++20`'s ranges.

Comment: @Fureeish No, I mean why does it have to be range-based? Why not `for (int index = 0; index <100; ++index)`?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler maybe OP is curious whether there is a support for range-based computations. Maybe OP is just curious in other ways of achieving the same. Either way, I agree with you asking for the reason.

Comment: *"Would be at least non-memory-optimized."* What?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I guess that OP means that a container needs to be created in memory for that. It would be nice, if OP could give more explanations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C++20` will have them as a part of the standard library, but as of right now, you can use Eric Niebler's `ranges-v3` from his [github](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

What you want to do can be easily achieved by `ranges::view::iota`, which *lazily* generates the consecutive elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace ranges;

    for (int i : view::iota(0, 10)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

prints: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. Given the fact that `view`s are *lazy*, at no point you have all 10 integers in your memory from the range. They are generated *on demand*.